# PHP: get data from json array without loop

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have data i want to get from array without loop.

I want to get "value" of "link_click" for example, how can i make this work?

I tried: but this not working.

```
$stats = json_decode($data, false);
$link_click= $stats->data->actions->action_type->['link_click']->value;


{
   "data": [
      {
         "actions": [
            {
               "action_type": "comment",
               "value": 2
            },
            {
               "action_type": "link_click",
               "value": 636
            },
            {
               "action_type": "post_like",
               "value": 2
            },
            {
               "action_type": "page_engagement",
               "value": 640
            },
            {
               "action_type": "post_engagement",
               "value": 640
            }
         ],
```

Comment: This sounds a lot like a homework assignment. Please post what you have tried. This is not a code generation site!

Comment: Since all your action entries have the action_type, you will need to loop over them and add a conditional to check against its value being "link_click". Better question: Why is looping not an option in this case?

Comment: @nLee, this code come from facebook api i tried to get the data using: '$link_click= $stats->data->actions->action_type->['link_click']->value;'

Comment: @Mario Wenig, can you give me example?

Comment: Look up 'foreach php' or 'php forach json array'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you can make it possible only if you know the index of the `action_type:link_click`. If you know the index, you can do it by. (Answer is with respect to the data you have shown above).

```
$stats = json_decode($data, true);
$link_click= $stats['data']['actions'][1]['value'];
```

Loop example (on request):

```
$stats = json_decode($data, true);
$value = 0;
foreach($stats['data']['actions'] as $action) {
    if ($action->action_type == 'link_click') {
        $value = $action->value;
    }    
}

echo $value; //This is your value
```

Comment: HI, can you give me also loop example? Thanks.

Comment: Will work, IF and ONLY IF resulting json data doesn't change. Careful trusting external data without doing your own validation on what data you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [JsonPath](https://github.com/Peekmo/JsonPath) to get the value